# how can i disable back button in paypal express checkout

Tags: php, paypal

I'm working with the paypal express checkout, it is working fine for me. Only issue is the back button of paypal, when my payment is done and when I press the back button of the browser still it shows me the paypal amount page, it should not t be happen, Can anyone please tell me how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you set a redirect rule so that once payment is done it will be redirected back to site automatically?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#definition-redirect_urls